# Creating an activerecord object with new relationship from select query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I would like to create a list of model objects that designate a new relationship without having to use raw sql.

Suppose I have the following models:

```
class MealCombination < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :drink
   belongs_to :food
end

class Food < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :meal_combinations
end

class Drink < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :meal_combinations
end
```

I would like to create a list of MealCombination objects that do not presently exist in the database.

Say my query would look something like this:

```
select distinct DRINK.id, FOOD.id from FOOD, DRINK where DRINK.alchohol_volume > 5 and FOOD.spice_factor > 45;
```

What is the most efficient way to create the `MealCombination` objects from this selection?

Iterating through an array returned back from the raw sql seems inefficient. I do not want to persist the objects into the database.

Comment: You have a list of meal combination and want to know which are in the database and which are not? im not sure i understand what you want

Comment: What I understand is you are trying to select all the `food` and `drink` from the db and use those ids to generate a list of all the possible `meal_combinations` in an efficient way. But you don't want to persist the `meal_combination` records?

Comment: Yes. That is correct Diego. The meal_combinations will be new relationships that don't exist in the database.

Comment: how do you know if that meal_combination is valid or not ?

Comment: I think you misunderstand my question. I want to create new MealCombinations that do not exist on the database. Their validity is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would probably be to create a view called "meal_combinations" in your database which will represent your select query you want to do.  ActiveRecord should treat the view as a table for the most part, but you should definitely add

```
  def read_only?
    true
  end
```

to any class definition that uses a view.  The main disadvantage to having a lot of views is that they make database migrations a little more of a pain to manage if you ever want to change columns in the underlying tables.

Comment: I only just noticed your comment. Thank you, that's a good work around.